# Tortoisesvn revert and undo revert

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tortoisesvn

I had to send a msi to a colleague, but wasn't finished with enhancements, so I wanted to revert to say Revision 6798, create the msi and then get back to where I was with the enhancements. Before I reverted, I committed at Revision 6809.

I think I became confused with the 'update to item' and 'revert to this revision' options after I did the initial 'revert to this revision' which was Revision 6798. Anyways, I've tried both with regards to Revision 6809 I think, but when I open Visual Studio some of the projects are unavailable.

I couldn't have lost some of the changes could I?
How do I just get my code back to Revision 6809 and everything working in Visual Studio again?

Comment: Can you see the revision 6809 when you right click on your project folder->TortoiseSVN->ShowLog? So, you can "revert to this revision" by right click on the revision, I think.

Comment: Yes I tried that, but it still gives the errors in VS. Not sure whether I should revert to each revision inbetween?

Comment: What type of errors do you get from VS?

Comment: A pop-up with this: "One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly. Please see the Output Window for details." and then in the Solution Explorer I can't expand some of the projects and they have "(unavailable)" behind their names.

Comment: I would suggest that you can re-check out the project from the repository. I think it will get back to the latest revision that you commit, if you know that your last commit was in the case that the project was working correctly.

Comment: Thanks, re-checking out again worked, although I did it in a different folder. However, I did manage to get the original folder back to the correct code again. I fooled around a lot, but I think I reverted again and then updated to the latest revision, 6809. Ignorance can waste time. I appreciate your help mhmtztmr!